# Socket set option explanation

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have small piece of code

```
boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay option(true);
boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* sock = new boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket(ios);
sock->set_option(option);
_session_acceptor.async_accept(*sock, 
                boost::bind(&server::playerAccept, this, sock, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

If i call `set_option` on socket before accepting server dont accept any connections. But if i call `set_option` after connections are accepted. Is there any magic?

Comment: '_session_acceptor' should be renamed. Prefix underscores are reserved for use by library wrtiers.

Comment: @mark: No, here they're not. `__this` and `_This` is reserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call `set_option` on acceptor, not socket. Example from my project:

```
 Listener::Listener(int port)
            : acceptor(io, ip::tcp::endpoint(ip::tcp::v4(), port))
            , socket(io) {
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::no_delay opt_nodelay(true);
    acceptor.set_option(opt_nodelay);
    start_accept();
```